# What is 'prototype learning' in computer vision?

Tags: terminology, definition, computer-vision

I was reading some papers about semantic and instance segmentation (e.g. [YOLACT](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.02689.pdf)) and often encountered the term 'prototype learning'. Could you please explain this concept?

Comment: A prototype is a dictionary image used as a mask to factor an image into component parts. When this has been done, the image has been spelt or learned in terms of the odd looking shapes in the dictionary.

Comment: Do you have an example or some reference with more details on this topic?

Comment: The example that you linked to should suffice, if it does not look up other dictionary image reconstruction methods.